# What's the difference between `alias` and `typedef`?

Tags: d

All this time I've been using `alias`, but today I discovered by chance that D has `typedef`.  Interesting enough, TDPL doesn't even cover it as far as I can tell (not even listed in `D Keywords` nor the Errata).  The [site does cover it](http://www.d-programming-language.org/cpptod.html#typedefs), but it doesn't talk about it much.  My code compiles with either, but what is the difference between the two, and when should I use `typedef` over `alias`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`alias` creates a new name for an existing one. `typedef` only works on types, and actually creates a new type:

```
alias int A;
typedef int B;

pragma(msg, is(A == int)); // true
pragma(msg, is(B == int)); // false
```

With `typedef`, you can also change the default initializer:

```
typedef int A = 42;

A a;
A[5] b;

void main()
{
    assert(a == 42);
    foreach(i; b) assert(i == 42);
}
```

`alias` is more general. It also works with symbols:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv : to;

alias to!(string) toString;

void main()
{
    int a;
    alias a b;
    a = 1;
    writeln(b); // 1

    string s = toString(2);
    writeln(s); // 2
}
```

`alias` is also used when you want to merge overload sets:

```
import std.stdio;

class Base
{
    void foo() { writeln("base"); }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    alias super.foo foo; // merge overload sets

    void foo(int i) { writeln("derived"); }
}

void main()
{
    auto a = new Derived;
    a.foo(); // base
    a.foo(0); // derived
}
```

Without the explicit merge, calling `Base.foo` using an instance of `Derived` is not allowed, because `Derived.foo` hides it by default.

This isn't only required for classes; if functions from two different imported modules are to overload each other, they must be merged explicitly with `alias`.

`typedef` is deprecated. As of DMD version 2.057, using `typedef` requires the `-d` (for "deprecated") flag to compile.

[This pull request](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/300) adds a template `TypeDef` to `std.typecons` replicating the functionality of `typedef` in the standard library.

Answer (score 7):

The 'typedef' keyword is a remnant of D1, and was always intended to be deprecated. As of D 2.057, it was fully deprecated. You should always use alias when working with D2.

Comment: alias is a generalized aliasing feature; you can use it to alias fields, functions, variables, types, and so on. It was decided that this was better design than having typedef which only works for types. Furthermore, typedef is actually a really poor choice of keyword for what it does.

Comment: @Zor: Weird... it seemed pretty intuitive ('define' a new 'type' based on an existing one) and it was actually extremely useful in defining HANDLEs and lots of other things...

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's the thing, it *doesn't* define a new type. Consider in C++ this: `struct f{}; struct g{};`; these are two defined classes. This is not: `struct f{}; typedef f g;`. Although the specific use of `f` or `g` behaves, the same, in the latter this is illegal: `void x(f); void x(g);`.

Comment: typedef still has several use-cases and will be turned into a library feature.